# Are temporary hit points counted when considering total damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, temporary-hit-points

For some damage like a vampire's bite attack or the [*harm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/harm) spell, your maximum HP is reduced based on the damage taken. What happens if some or all of that damage is absorbed by the target's temporary hit points? Does that count as damage taken or not?